# .val() on field name with []

Tags: javascript, jquery, yii2

Auto Field generated by YII2

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="TABELACOSearch[ID_VANTIVE]" value="">
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var teste = $("input[name=TABELACOSearch[ID_VANTIVE]]").val();
console.log(teste)

});
```

I believe the problem is the field name with [], but i can't change the name of the field , and i just need to copy the value from 5 fields like that
OBS : i can't add class and ID . What can i do ??

And the error :

```
jquery.js:1468 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[name=TABELACOSearch[ID_VANTIVE]]
at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery.js:1468)
at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery.js:2125)
at Sizzle.select (jquery.js:2546)
at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery.js:869)
at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery.js:2792)
at jQuery.fn.init (jquery.js:2909)
at jQuery (jquery.js:75)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.php?TABELACOSearch[ID_VANTIVE]=&TABELACOSearch[ID_VANTIVE_ANTIGO]=&TABELACOSearch[STATUS]=&TABELACOSearch[NUM_LP]=&TABELACOSearch[CLIENTE]=&r=qualidade:135)
at n (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith (jquery.min.js:2)
```

Comment: use quotes.....

Comment: Specifically `$('input[name="TABELACOSearch[ID_VANTIVE]"]').val();`

Answer (score 1):

You can escape it with two backslash as mentioned here:
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/